# VBA Excel Error 400 (1004) on Workbooks.Open

Tags: excel, vba

The code loads an Excel file into an existing worksheet. The problem is that it often works and only sometimes an Error 400 appears, or the message that the "Open" function for "Workbooks" does not work. I have already tried several things, but I am slowly getting stumped. Here is the code:

```
Sub loadData()

On Error GoTo MyHandler

Dim ActSht As Worksheet
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim CurrBook As Workbook
Dim OpenBook As Workbook

Set ActSht = ActiveSheet
Set CurrBook = ThisWorkbook

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Neue Datei auswählen", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*xlsx*), *xlsx*")

If FileToOpen <> False Then

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)

OpenBook.Sheets("Items").UsedRange.Copy
CurrBook.Sheets("New_File").Range("A1").PasteSecial XlPasteValues

OpenBook.Close False
MsgBox "Neue Datei wurde geladen"

Else
MsgBox "Keine Datei geladen"

End If

Application.DisplayAlters = True

ActSht.Activate

Exit Sub

MyHandler:
MsgBox "Fehler: " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Tried moving into new Modul, Trust Center Setting, other ways to load the File and so on

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Excel does not have any errors that say "does not work". Hint: give the actual, full, error message to get the best results

Comment: If it works sometimes and not others then it is likely to be the file that is being opened that is the issue. Examine the files that don't work - in what way are they "different" to the ones that do work. For example do they contain Links to files you do not have access to - in which case use `UpdateLinks:=0`

Comment: The problem is that the same file can sometimes be loaded and sometimes not.

Comment: And the error message is ...

Comment: And the error is that the 'Open' function for 'Workbooks' does not work. This is the Err.Description. If I have no GoTo then it only say Error 400

Comment: That is not an Excel error message so I can't help you

Comment: If you get an error with workbooks.open then there is some problem with the selected file path which is preventing excel from opening the file.  There's no way for us to know what that problem is though.  Does it always fail on the same file?  If Yes then you need to investigate the cause.  For a failing file, can you open it manually via File>>Open for example?

Comment: No, it also works with the same file. Sometimes the error occurs and sometimes not. Sometimes the file cannot be opened and without doing anything it works on the next attempt.

Comment: Run-time Error '1004' - Method 'Open' of object 'Workbooks' failed

Comment: And can you reliably always open the problem file manually?  It's very difficult for us to debug when the problem is not consistent.  Your code looks fine.

Comment: Yes. The file is saved in the group folder. But there is never more than one person with the file open at the same time when the error occurs. Furthermore, the file has a few power queries

Comment: Maybe it's because the File has about 18.000 rows?

Comment: That's not really a large file though.  It may be a problem related to an add-in: try disabling all add-ins and see if anything changes.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Sorry I don't have much else to suggest.